# Unable to find the element on emulator screen of Android app

Tags: automation, appium-android

The element appears within the appium view but unfortunately the element does not seems visible while automating it.

```
private AndroidDriver driver;
String idOfCNIC = "com.tez.androidapp:id/imageViewNICDetails";

this.driver.findElement(By.id(idOfCNIC))`
```

Following is the driver initialization code :

```
private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static AndroidDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("deviceName", "920121cb3c7fc34a");
            caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
            caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
            caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
            caps.setCapability("app", "path_of_app");
            (InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
            try {
                driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: the element does not seems visible means? is the element in scroll view? Going to element you have scroll ?

Comment: No scroll view in this case. The element is appearing on app screen but appium is unable to locate it.

Comment: can you share the code of driver initialization and how you are setting capabilities?

Comment: waht's the error message ?

Comment: @SurajJogdand yes!!

`private static AndroidDriver driver;
public static AndroidDriver getDriver() {
if (driver == null) {
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities ();
caps.setCapability ("deviceName", "920121cb3c7fc34a");
caps.setCapability ("platformName", "Android");
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
caps.setCapability("app", "path_of_app");
(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
}return driver;
}`

Comment: @AlImran, "An element could not be located".

Comment: could you please edit your question and the code there?

Comment: @SurajJogdand done!

Answer (score -1):

Hi could you please use following versions of Appium java client and Selenium:

1. Appium Java-Client : 6.0.0-BETA5
2. Selenium-server : 3.9.1 Appium
3. Desktop as Appium Inspector : 1.6.1

Also please try with the following code for driver initialization :

```
private static AndroidDriver<?> driver;

    public static AndroidDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "920121cb3c7fc34a");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"Appium ");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "6.0.1");
            caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "path_of_app");
            caps.setCapability("appWaitActivity", "*");
            try {
                driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

I hope this solves your problem. Thanks!

Comment: With your driver initialization, i have came across new Error, cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class Steps.loginSteps.
Can you pls help me resolving it too.

Comment: Same behavior Suraj!
No progress .